# Reading geotiff metadata on android

Tags: java, android, geotiff

I am searching for a way to read geotiff metadata, but imageIO is not supported on android and sanselan can't read geotiff meta. Is there any way to just read it?

Comment: You need to use PROJ.4 library that supports Android http://augusttown.blogspot.com/2010/03/using-java-map-projection-library-in.html

Comment: Another tool is GDAL which inherently uses PRO4.J library but it is still WIP for Android http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid

Comment: Thanks, i will try the GDAL solution